# How can I abort an async-await function after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, async-await

For example, the following is an async function:

```
async function encryptPwd() {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(5);
  const encryptedPwd = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  return encryptedPwd;
}
```

If the server is lagging a lot, I want to abort this activity and return an error. How can I set a timeout for like 10 sec (for example)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could wrap the hash function in another promise.

```
function hashWithTimeout(password, salt, timeout) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt).then(resolve, reject);
        setTimeout(reject, timeout);
    });
}


const encryptedPwd = await hashWithTimeout(password, salt, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: Could the `async` keyword be dropped from the outer function, since it's returning a promise on its own?

Comment: @Mark - while it does return a promise, keep it mind that it only actually returns a promise after all the code before it had ran & done, so therefor. this is why the `async`  keyword much be used in the function hold the `await` calls, so it will be a promise at run-time.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

```
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, ms, 'HASH_TIMED_OUT');
  });
}

 const encryptedPwd = await Promise.race(() => bcrypt.hash(password, salt), wait(10 * 1000));

 if (encryptedPwd === 'HASH_TIMED_OUT') {
    // handle the error
 }
 return encryptedPwd;
```